# How to replace *all* double bracketed text with a modified version of itself when the content is unknown

Tags: php, regex, templates, variables

I am creating a PHP template page that I dont want the end-user to have to write PHP code in. So I would like to set up a system that replaces **[[string]]** with **$string**. This way I dont have to maintain a list of variables to look up, I can just use the name within the brackets and if there is a matching variable in the code, it will replace it.

I know how to capture all the double bracketed text.

```
$text = 'string [[of]] text [[to]] test'
preg_match_all("/\[\[[^\]]*\]\]/", $text, $matches);
```

I think that preg_match_all returns an array of all the matches, but the only way I can seem to have access into it is something like $matches[1], but this won't work since I dont know how many matches there will be.

I have tried

```
foreach ($matches as $match) { 
   ///code
}
```

But I think this foreach is looking at the whole array, not the inside.

Once I get each match I know how to remove the two brackets and turn it into a variable PHP will recognize, instead of a string.

```
str_replace($match, ${substr($match, 2, -2)}, $text)
```

If you have a better idea of how to turn double bracketed text in HTML file into variables PHP will read without knowing what is in the double brackets first I would be interested in another solution as well.

Comment: I have an added thought that perhaps this is not secure because I would be turning something a user-submitted into a variable. Perhaps they could get some information that PHP had on the page that I did not necessarily want them to have.  So maybe I have to maintain a list?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($matches)` to see how `preg_match_all` has captured your data.  Generally, you want to do `foreach ($matches[0] as $match)`.  And your concern may be valid re: unsanitized input, but I can't think of any trouble off the top of my head from user-named variables; maybe someone else can chime in on that.

Comment: One other thing: without a capturing group (parentheses) in your `preg_match_all`, it won't grab the text inside the double brackets.  I think you want `preg_match_all("/\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]/", $text, $matches);`.

Comment: Sorry, it's late.  `foreach ($matches as $match)`, and then `$match[1]` will contain your matched text (using the capturing group I noted above).  No need for the `str_replace` later.

Comment: You might extend the character class to not match a whitespace char, an openin `[` and for example also not a dollar sign `(?<!\S)\[\[\K[^][\s$]+(?=]](?!\S))` https://regex101.com/r/qeRuFM/1 See https://3v4l.org/is7cK

Comment: @FoulFoot I want to capture the double brackets at first because I want to replace them with the new info.

Comment: @DavidEdwards Do you want to keep the double brackets in the replacement?

Comment: No, they would be removed. So [[variable]]  --> $variable. I am going to try @michel solution, but have not had the chance yet.

Answer (score -1):

`preg_match_all('/\[\[.*?\]\]/',$string,$matches);`

Will give $matches:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[of]]
            [1] => [[to]]
        )

)
```

So you can loop `$matches[0]`